# Loading the favicon async / non-blocking

Tags: javascript, html, favicon, preload

I want to load the favicon non-blocking and let the browser prioritize.

```
<link rel="preload" href="/assets/favicon.ico"
      as="image" onload="this.rel='shortcut icon'" sizes="196x196">
<noscript><link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="196x196" 
                href="/assets/favicon.ico"></noscript>
```

This works - but Chrome prints the info:

> The resource http://.../assets/favicon.ico was preloaded using link
>   preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load
>   event. Please make sure it Please make sure it has an appropriate `as`
>   value and it is preloaded intentionally.

Is this ok to use?

Comment: Preloading makes no sense unless you try to use the resource later on. The favicon is handled by the browser directly. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @NineBerry using preload allows the browser to better prioritize downloads + preloads are not blocking. This works like a charm with CSS. It also works well with the favicon but Chrome prints the above message...

Comment: @NineBerry I am trying to figure out wether I am using a glitch here with the favicon or if this is legit. The browser also handles CSS directly, but you can always help the browser to prioritize things better, that's what I am doing with the favicon.